# {beamer} use \insertsection to load image in section frame - replace spaces

Tags: beamer, includegraphics

I have a custom section frame defined for my presentations. I'd like to load an image with the name of the section title. Problem is that LaTeX usually fails to load image if their names contain spaces. So I'm looking for a solution to replace the spaces (and by chance other special chars too) when passing `\insertsection` as parameter to `\includegraphics`.

here is a (not) working minimal example:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{default}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\setbeamertemplate{section page}{{
    \begin{frame}{\insertsectionhead}
        \begin{columns}
            \begin{column}{0.65\textwidth}                 
                 this should load an image with name
                  \texttt{some-section-with-spaces.png}
                 in the on the right of this text (if that exists...)
            \end{column}
            \begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}% 
                \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{%
                %% how to  replace spaces with minus or underscore here
                    \insertsection%
                }
            \end{column}
        \end{columns}
    \end{frame}
}}
\AtBeginSection{
  \sectionpage
}
\begin{document}
  \section{some section with spaces in name}
\end{document}
```

Comment: An easy workaround would be to name your images by the section number instead of the name.

Comment: @samcarter too easy to find that out myself **;o)** thanks!

Comment: Or use the `shortsection` instead to define an alternative title with spaces replaced.

Comment: Off-topic: you don't need `\usetheme{default}`, as the name says, this theme is loaded per default

Comment: @samcarter that would be a *hidden dependency* which I'd like to avoid. But on the other hand it has the beauty that the image name could differ from the section title...

Comment: mmmm, I just saw that you are already using the short section title for the frametitle of the section pages. Maybe not such a good idea then.

Comment: In case you want to pursue your original approach with the section title, then maybe the grf­file package could help.

Comment: @samcarter looks like the `{grf­file}` package is my way to go (not only because of this special case....) So please make an answer from your comment so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Approach 1**

A simple workaround could be to use the section number to name the images:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
%\usetheme{default}
\usepackage{inputenc}
\setbeamertemplate{section page}{
    \begin{frame}{\insertsectionhead}
        \begin{columns}
            \begin{column}{0.65\textwidth}                 
                 this should load an image with name
                  \texttt{some-section-with-spaces.png}
                 in the on the right of this text (if that exists...)
            \end{column}
            \begin{column}{0.45\textwidth}% 
                \includegraphics[width=0.7\linewidth]{\thesection}
            \end{column}
        \end{columns}
    \end{frame}
}

\AtBeginSection{
  \sectionpage
}

\begin{document}
  \section{some section with spaces in name}

  \section{title}
\end{document}
```

**Approach 2**

If you want to stick to your original plan and use spaces in file names, then the `grf­file` package could help.